# Why do i get error "query must have atleast one destination field" in access?

Tags: ms-access

I get the error "query must have atleast one destination field" when i click a button in the form.

On click of button VB Code:
    Dim stDocName As String, valore As Integer

```
stDocName = "Solleciti_Odl_Rilasciati_per_form_new_weekly_005_Del_dup_records"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, stDocName, acFormatXLS

valore = MsgBox("Estrazione Dati Completata!", vbInformation)
```

on clicking the button, I get a dialog box for document "Solleciti_Odl_Rilasciati_per_form_new_weekly_005_Del_dup_records"
 to be saved or opened. after giving ok, the above error comes.

Please give me idea why we get this error.

Comment: hi is this from your application? if it is then just search for the error message in your code and check for the validation logic. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The second parameter of `DoCmd.OutputTo` is the object to export.
   Are you sure that there is actually a query named `Solleciti_Odl_Rilasciati_per_form_new_weekly_005_Del_dup_records` in your Access database?
2. If yes, does the query actually contain something (like, a `SELECT` query)?
   I just found out that I get exactly the same error as you ("query must have at least one destination field") when I try to export a query that's completely empty.